# div scrollTop() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

so I have this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TLkmK/

```
<div class="test" style="height:100px;width:70px;overflow:auto">
    sadfsadf

    saf
    sadf
    saf
    s
    af
    saf
    saf
    sadf
    sadfsafsafsaf
    sadfsaf

    sadfsafsadf

    sadfsaf
    sa
    dfsa
    fsadf
</div>
alert($('.test').scrollTop());
```

try scrolling down the bar

I'm trying to get the scrollTop() property for the div but it's always returning 0 instead of the proper scrollTop

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: scrollTop gets vertical position of the scrollbar, so it will alert 0 on page load, each and everytime

Comment: Check for it at the right time, like when someone has srolled not on page load when page isn't scrolled at all so it's 0.

Comment: you have a few answers below please mark one correct..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do something like this

```
$('.test').scroll(function() {
    alert($(this).scrollTop());
});
```

that will alert a new value each time, or use console.log

```
  $('.test').scroll(function() {
        console.log($(this).scrollTop());
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

It will always be `0` when you initially load the page because you haven't had time to scroll yet. I'd also recommend using `console.log` instead of `alert` so you can continue to use the page.

You can use the `scroll` event to listen for the user scrolling, and then update whatever you want based on that. I can't say without your usecase, but you should use some event anyway to trigger reading the position.

http://jsfiddle.net/TLkmK/1/

```
var el = $('.test');
console.log(el.scrollTop());

el.on('scroll', function(){
  console.log(el.scrollTop());
});
```